# written out bytes size and actually size are different using python's file.write()

Tags: python, python-requests

here is my code , it's really simple, I download a file(with lib requests ) and save it to disk,but the size i got is different from actually size write to disk

```
mus_resp =r.get("http://audio.xmcdn.com/group7/M07/21/73/wKgDWlbmOa3TD0D_AArDQp_Mj5Y641.m4a",headers=headers, stream=True)

#print len(mus_resp.content) here is 705346 bytes
fd = open( "file", 'w') 
fd.write(mus_resp.content)
fd.flush()
fd.close()
exit()
print os.path.getsize('file')  here is 708677 bytes
```

Comment: You opened the file in text mode, so end-of-line conversions were performed.  Use `'wb'` to write in binary mode instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is binary data, not text, and it likely contains `\n` characters semi-randomly (they don't mean newlines, it's just the same byte as ASCII newline). When you write them to a text mode file on Windows, it's seamlessly converting to `\r\n` (Windows standard line endings), bloating the final file. Open the file in binary mode and you'll disable line ending conversions:

```
fd = open("file", 'wb')  # 'wb' means write binary mode
```

Comment: thank you so much, i used to be a java programmer, i thought it's the same as java's write byte array , but why the documentations doesn't mention that

Comment: @kevin: Python 2 doesn't have a clear separation between binary data and text; the `str` type represents a subset of text values as well as holding binary data (with a separate `unicode` type that's text only, and handles most or all Unicode values). If you're learning Python or writing new code, I'd strongly recommend going with Python 3, where the text and binary types are completely separated, so you can't make this mistake without getting an error (specifically, a file opened in text mode only accepts `str`, the text type, and binary mode requires `bytes`-like binary data types).

Comment: One of the hardest (non-automatable, hard to write in a cross-version compatible way) parts of migrating Py2 code to Py3 is dealing with the change from Py2's `str` (ASCII text and binary data) + `unicode` (most or all text) system to Py3's `str` (all text) + `bytes` (binary data) system (the only other problem of comparable significance is converting the `/` operator, and there is a `__future__` import to make it possible to write Py2 code portably there, so only legacy code need have that problem). Migrating now will make things easier down the line.